# How are the layers used in MagicaVoxel?

Tags: magicavoxel

I can't figure out how they are used, how to actually use them, or what they are meant for. I would have thought I could assign blocks or colour palettes to a layer...turn it off and temporarily hide/delete it while I work with specific sections etc. I'm clicking around and highlighting and trying to get it to work but all I can do is assign the entire box of voxels to 1 layer and turn that on/off.

I've been unable to find any documentation explaining how to use the layers.